# Having Issue on Loading Array Items to JS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load items of an array to a varaible as string to use it dynamically in the page

```js
var data = ["Sat 17 Jan", "Wed 14 Jan", "Wed 7 Jan"]
var str;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    str = '<button class="btn btn-success">'+data[i]+'</button>';
}
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I am getting now is only the last button in the console as:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Wed 7 Jan</button>
```

but I need to get

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Sat 17 Jan</button><button class="btn btn-success">Wed 14 Jan</button><button class="btn btn-success">Wed 7 Jan</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append the every new button to the string and for that use `+=`.

```js
var data = ["Sat 17 Jan", "Wed 14 Jan", "Wed 7 Jan"]
var str = "";

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    str += '<button class="btn btn-success">'+data[i]+'</button>';
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks void this is working but when I try to present the `str` in the page I am getting `undefined` at the beginning!  Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/j11GuNiiDD) to see what is happening?

Comment: Try this http://www.bootply.com/4olbJlLNqm , you need to do `var str = ""` instead of just `var str;`

Comment: Sure I just had to wait for 10 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = ["Sat 17 Jan", "Wed 14 Jan", "Wed 7 Jan"];

console.log($.map(data, function(aDate){
  return '<button class="btn btn-success">'+ aDate +'</button>';
}).join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You re-assign str every loop cycle. Try this:

```
str = str + "your html";
```

in your for loop

Comment: Why are you using longhand??  `str += "your html"` is much simpler